# mod_jk module on IBM HTTP Server failing with syntax error

Tags: mod-jk, ibmhttpserver

We are trying to add mod_jk module to IBM http server but failing with syntax error. We tried multiple configuration available on internet but no luck.

Below is screenshot for configuration in httpd.conf file

[image: Config]

Below is screenshot of error

[image: Error]

We tried both absolutely path and relative path. It says mod_jk.so file is in incorrect format. We tried to download file from

- http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/linux/jk-1.2.31/x86_64/

My question is mod_jk Mule supported in IBM HTTP Server, if yes, where can we get its compiled file for HTTD version 9.0.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like an AIX system reporting a shared library load error, but you linked to a linux module.   You can't use a linux native library in an AIX program.

Further, you shouldn't use IHS + mod_jk. It's completely unsupported when using it with anything that would require mod_jk. Just use Apache.

Comment: makes sense. No online documentation show, if IHS + mod_jk is supported or not. thanks for details.